# How does android client communicate with the server on PC?

Tags: android, sockets

I'm making a chat app(like wechat) and the client is on my android device, the server is on my PC. The server is coded with Java in eclipse and listens on a port(like 8082). The client creates a socket with an IP and port(the same as the server, eg. 8082). When I set the IP to 127.0.0.1 in the socket, it says "connection refused". What should the IP be? I've searched a lot and nothing is found. I'm new to the socket communication. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Use the local lan ip of your pc.

Comment: Google: find local lan ip address command prompt. There are several ways to find it.

Comment: @blackapps you mean the result of ipconfig command ?

Comment: Yes. use ipconfig. But it can produce a lot of info... ;-) You have to scroll back a lot..

Comment: @blackapps Thanks. But the output of ipconfig on my PC has only four lines information and one IPV4 address. I tried with the IPv4 address, it says "failed to connect to /10.58.XX (port 8082) connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)". What's the reason?

Comment: Did you (in your java server code) bind the socket to an ip? Dont do such things. Further the firewall of the pc can prevent incoming connections. Switch it off for a test.

Comment: @blackapps No, I didn't bind the server socket to an IP. Here's the code:  ServerSocket serverSocket = ServerSocket(8082, 27);  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()

Comment: @blackapps any new ideas about this? Looking forward to your reply, thanks a lot !

Comment: You did not comment on firewall.

Comment: urther you could try a browser on your Android device to connect to ip:port.

Comment: @blackapps My IP is 10.58.XX. When I type in the IP and port in the browser on my android device, it's still not working. How to comment on firewall? Really appreciate it.

Comment: `My IP is 10.58.XX` ? That should be the ip of your pc. Not of you or your Android device. `How to comment on firewall?` Well i said: `Further the firewall of the pc can prevent incoming connections. Switch it off for a test. `. But i heard nothing of you so i said: `You did not comment on firewall.` And then you said...

Comment: @blackapps 10.58.XX.XX is truly the IP of my PC, okay, I see whay you meant, I'll try to switch the firewall off and make a test. Thanks a lot!